# How does one get a random children of a Firebase node?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First off, here's my Database structure:

[image: firebase database structure]

My goal was to get a random Question object from the "DE" node to later display it, and as there's no builtin support for querying a random child I have to get a random Object myself, from that iterator, somehow.

Currently, I have this code, but am confused on how to string it together:

```
    DatabaseReference questionsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions").child("DE");

questionsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int questionCount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        int rand = random.nextInt(questionCount);
        Iterator itr = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
    }
    // onCancelled(){}
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/40765613 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/40853157 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/42186839

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, I believe only the third link is actually what I was asking about (first and second questions are not what this is), and in that solution it first creates a List and then adds everything to it, just to get one thing back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just have to do enough `itr.next()` until the iterator is at the `n`th position (where `n` is the random number from `nextInt()`) and then you can simply get the Object you want with `getValue()`, the example below should show it well:

```
questionsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions").child("DE");

questionsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int questionCount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        int rand = random.nextInt(questionCount);
        Iterator itr = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        for(int i = 0; i < rand; i++) {
            itr.next();
        }
        childSnapshot = (DataSnapshot) itr.next();
        question = childSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: If your database is very big, you can use `Firebase Functions` for this purpose!