# How to get random UId everytime from Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having an activity in which there is a button get uid, I am registering users and it is creating unique id for each user in Firebase database. What I want is  when i click the button it will choose the Uid from the available Uids in firebase database and show that id , but the ids must be random and it must be from the database of users who register themselves in the app. How to get random UId everytime?

Comment: Do you want to fetch the UID that Firebase generates for that particular user?

Comment: Yes ..bt i want to fetch random uid everytime , like the pointer goes through each id and give me random uid everytime like shuffling

Comment: i want to make chat app to connect randomly using uids , is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: Firebase has a codelab to make a chat app here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853157/firebase-random-query/40853780#40853780, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765613/get-random-child-from-firebase-database, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035087/how-does-one-get-a-random-children-of-a-firebase-node and more from this list: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+random+child

Comment: You can store the userID in an array and choose them randomly. If you want to pursue with that path. I can show you.

Comment: But then the userid will act as local how can i implement it in global level..means i store the id in type of global storage so that i cam access it when i want to connect

Comment: Go checkout my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038712/how-do-i-retrieve-a-random-object-from-firebase-using-a-sequential-id/53330758#53330758). I think it is exactly what you are looking for! let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible . Since Firebase will return a UID that is associated with a particular user.

I read the docs [getIDToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdToken)

Unless you have stored the passwords & emails of all the users who registered, then you can request the UID one by one and store them in an array.Then you can do a Random function based of the length of the array.