# Is this the correct way to retrieve data from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Introduction**

I am doing an app for school and I have choosen Firebase due to their extensive videos and online material that can help you a lot. But problems like these when you are new to something could be solved here by more experienced people.

**What I have understood so far**

I want to retrieve a random data object from the realtime database from Firebase. I've seen other posts suggesting examples included in the tutorial videos but none seem to work for me:

I have a DB with questions uploaded by the users with the next structure:
[image]

(Forget why it says messages instead of questions since I was following their tutorials line by line trying to accomplish my goal)

In order to retrieve data you have to create a reference to the DB as:

```
//DB Object
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
//This will only reference the message part of the DB
private DatabaseReference mQuestionsDBReference;
```

and the initialize it as:

```
private void loadQuestionsDB() {
    //Access point
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); //Instanciate the object
    mQuestionsDBReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages"); //Only reference the 
    "messages" part
    //System.out.println("[DEBUG] " + mQuestionsDBReference.getDatabase());
}
```

(I initialize here everything in a function which is later called by `onCreate()`)

In order to select a random question from the DB I went with this solution:

```
private void loadRandomQuestion() {

    mQuestionsDBReference.startAt(randomNumber()).limitToFirst(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                System.out.println("[DEBUG-PLAY] Cargando!");
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    //Something I tried so maybe that was the problem I was facing :(
                    String question = dataSnap.child("-M3qlTuWw9TkD-LwQWYA").child("question").getValue().toString();
                    String answer1 = dataSnap.child("answer1").getValue().toString();
                    String answer2 = dataSnap.child("answer2").getValue().toString();
                    String answer3 = dataSnap.child("answer3").getValue().toString();
                    String answer4 = dataSnap.child("answer4").getValue().toString();

                    questionViewTxt.setText(question);
                    radioButton1.setText(answer1);
                    radioButton2.setText(answer2);
                    radioButton3.setText(answer3);
                    radioButton4.setText(answer4);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("[DEBUG] No children :/, that's a problem right there...");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**Problem and Goal**

I can not successfully retrieve a random question from the DB neither the one that I need.

The goal is to be able to retrieve a random question each time I press a Button or call the function `loadRandomQuestion()`.

Notes

```
- Instead of System.out.println() I could use Log
   - Instead of the above I could use the debugger
   - I know there are multiple listeners for referencedDB
   - I am at beginner level in this subject (3 days since this post)
   - I'm using Andriod Studio
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mQuestionsDBReference.startAt(randomNumber())` won't work, because:

1. You're not specifying what to order by, so `startAt(randomNumber())` will not "know" where to start.
2. You have no relevant number either as the key or as a property in the JSON, so there's nothing for Firebase to match on.

You seem to think that `startAt()` can be used with an offset, which is not the case. Firebase `startAt()`/`endAt()` queries are cursor based, meaning you need to specify a value to start at.

For example, you could do:

```
mQuestionsDBReference.orderByKey().startAt("-M3qm...Q2Tz-")...
```

or start at a specific question with:

```
mQuestionsDBReference.orderByChild("Question").startAt("¿question?")...
```

To allow random access:

1. Add a property with a predictable range of values to each question.
2. Calculate a random value within that range.
3. Then order by that property, and start at that value.

Also see:

- [Firestore: How to get random documents in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection), which is for Firestore but the same principles apply to Realtime Database
- [Get random child from Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765613/get-random-child-from-firebase-database)
- [Firebase - random query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853157/firebase-random-query)
- [How to get a random object from firebase database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186839/how-to-get-a-random-object-from-firebase-database-in-android)
- and more from these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+random+child+node)

Comment: Thank you very much not just for the answer but all the documentation and videos. Your team has created an awesome tool for absolute beginners and small startups. :D

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest loading all the questions to an ArrayList, which will make it much easier. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Hope this could somewhat help you, or give you an idea on how to improve your code, if not then I'm sorry I couldn't be much of a help!

This is a similar question (answered)

[Get random item from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145596/get-random-item-from-firebase)

Comment: What if there are THOUSANDS of questions. That would take a lot of space.

Comment: kinda helps me even if this was a Java question and not JS. Thanks mate!

Comment: I'm glad I kinda helped!